# How to terminate app script execution on condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following in an apps script program:

```
// get all email threads that match label from Sheet
 var threads = GmailApp.search ("label:" + label);
```

Because I move processed threads to another label, there are times when I have no unprocessed threads. How can I terminate the execution if there is no threads to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
if (!threads || threads.length < 1) {

    return;

}
```